# How to setup urls.py to work with app/urls.py and templates in src with Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

Trying to figure out how to setup my own project.

I created a new Django app to make a homepage.

**src/home/urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'views.index', name='index'),
]
```

**src/home/views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html", {})
```

**src/project/urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('home.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**src/templates/index.html:**

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

The reason this isn't in a templates folder inside of the home app is because I want to use this as my base template eventually for all apps and pages

Error reads:

```
ImportError at /
No module named 'views'
```

Using python 3.5 and django 1.9

EDIT*** changed to home.views.index

ERROR now reads:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
index.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you `home` is a *package* and you have `__init__.py` there.

You might also need to change `views.index` to `home.views.index` in your urls.py

Comment: @SierraKilo Change `views.index` to `home.views.index` as @alecxe suggested.

Comment: @selcuk now I get a different error saying the template doesn't exist .

Comment: Then your template loader is not configured correctly. Update your question to include your `settings.py` so that we can diagnose.

Comment: @SierraKilo you might need to tweak the [`TEMPLATES` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES).

Comment: THANKS!!!         'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")], But does this mean I cant have templates inside my other apps later? Will it always look here for them now? or does will it look inside the app first, and then here?

Comment: @SierraKilo set the [`APP_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#app-dirs) to `True` to let django include the `app/templates` directories too.

Answer (score 3):

**In Site-wide Urls.py do the Following:**

```
from app_name import urls as app_name_urls
from django.conf.urls import include

urlpatterns=[
path('',include(app_name_urls)
]
```

**In App/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views
urlpatterns=[
    #your paths go here
]
```